# Can I Summon Nature's Ally through a wall or floor?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The spell hasn't got a target, except maybe the grid you're placing the creature on. Does a grid position count as a target that you need line of sight to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## An [effect](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#effect) can't usually be created if [line of effect](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#lineofEffect) is blocked between the caster and the effect

A summoned creature is usually an [effect](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#effect), so while the spells [*summon nature's ally*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/summonNaturesAllyI.htm) and similar spells don't have a [target](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#targetorTargets), because the spells create an [effect](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#effect), the caster must have a clear [line of effect](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#lineofEffect) from himself to the spell's effect:

> A line of effect is a straight, unblocked path that indicates what a spell can affect. **A line of effect is canceled by a solid barrier.** It’s like line of sight for ranged weapons, except that it’s not blocked by fog, darkness, and other factors that limit normal sight. (*PH* 176)
>
> **You must have a clear line of effect** to any target that you cast a spell on or **to any space in which you wish to create an effect.** You must have a clear line of effect to the point of origin of any spell you cast. [...]
>
> An otherwise solid barrier with a hole of at least 1 square foot through it does not block a spell’s line of effect. Such an opening means that the 5-foot length of wall containing the hole is no longer considered a barrier for purposes of a spell’s line of effect.

Emphasis mine. This means, though, that you *can* summon creatures into an area into which your senses can't penetrate (such as an area of darkness through which you can't see); you just can't summon the creatures into that same area if the area of darkness is, in fact, an opaque [*wall of force*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/wallOfForce.htm) or something.